# Python IF Statement With Communicate() Function

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, subprocess

I am using a terminal command in my Python code using subprocesses, I am trying to check the communicate() function to check what the function returns and see if something is contained inside it. My function current returns both of the following depending on the outcome of the plates:

```
(b'No license plates found.\n', None) 
Plate Not Found

(b'plate0: 10 results\n    - SBG984\t confidence: 85.7017\n    -
SBG98\t confidence: 83.3453\n    - S8G984\t confidence: 78.3329\n    -
5BG984\t confidence: 76.6761\n    - S8G98\t confidence: 75.9766\n    -
SDG984\t confidence: 75.5532\n    - 5BG98\t confidence: 74.3198\n    -
SG984\t confidence: 73.3743\n    - SDG98\t confidence: 73.1969\n    -
BG984\t confidence: 71.7671\n', None) Plate Not Found
```

The code is the following:

```
def read_plate():
    alpr_out = alpr_subprocess().communicate()
    print(alpr_out)
    if "No license plates found." in alpr_out:
        print ("No results!")
    elif "SBG984" in alpr_out:
        print ("Found Plate")
    else:
        print("Plate Not Found")
```

As you can tell from this code, it should print "No results!" but it is instead printing "Plate Not Found", if the function returns the plate which is SBG984 the code will still return "No results!". I am guessing I am missing something simple and maybe somebody can spot it.

Comment: What is the output of `print(alpr_out)` and `print(type(alpr_out))`?

Comment: The print is above in the question but the type is <class 'tuple'> @arsho

Comment: Double check what the variable types are in your code.

Comment: @BaileyKocin What do you mean what variable types? alpr_out is tuple? Should still be able to check if something is contained the way I have done it

Comment: @CurtusB We just wanted to make sure it was a tuple. How would we know for sure?

Comment: That is what the print type is returning so i'd say that is it, the print out is in my question, it must be something very simple @BaileyKocin

Comment: Hint: consider the simpler example `print("zqu" in ("foobar", "bazqux"))`. This outputs `False`, even though the letters "zqu" appear inside "bazqux".

Comment: I posted after @arsho responded. If it were so simple why couldn't you figure it out yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alpr_out` is a tuple: `(b'No license plates found.\n', None)`

What you want to do is check the substring is `in` the first element of the tuple, not in the tuple itself:

```
def read_plate():
    alpr_out = alpr_subprocess().communicate()
    print(alpr_out)
    # Index first element with [0]
    if "No license plates found." in alpr_out[0].decode():
        print ("No results!")
    elif "SBG984" in alpr_out[0].decode():
        print ("Found Plate")
    else:
        print("Plate Not Found")
```

Comment: Your code is returning an error, I will add it to your answer

Comment: @CurtisB check now, I added `decode()` to convert from bytes to string